# Django - Load template with jQuery into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm working with a client that has a view that, after a user logs in, this view loads a template, that dynamically draws a canvas with jQuery, and generates an image copy of the canvas.

They want to protect the jQuery code, hiding the process in the python code.

I tried using PyExecJS, but it doesn't support jQuery, since there is no DOM.

I've also tried urllib2, mechanize and Selenium, but none worked.

Is there an alternative or have I missed something?

**Update/Resolution:** In case someone stumbles onto this question: I ended up using Selenium for Python to load the JS function, fed it the necessary data and extracted the image from it. It has a bit of an overhead, but since the main goal was to keep the JS code obfuscated, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to hide jquery code.

You can't hide jquery code from the user, because django processes python code before it serves up the template, there's no way to protect jquery code with python.  Really the best thing you can do is to minimize and obfuscate the code, but that only makes it difficult for human reading.